# Save variable returned by signal handler?

Tags: python, textview, pygtk, gtktreeview, signal-handling

I am writing an application in Python 2.7 using PyGTK 2. Basically I create TreeView widget, fill it with content and then check if the selection is changed. When it is true I want the selection to be printed in TextView box. My idea is to get selected value, update text and refresh widget. Here is how i get the selected value:

Definition:

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        someTextView = build_textview("some text")
        ...
        tree_selection = someTreeView.get_child().get_selection()
        tree_selection.connect("changed", self.selection_changed())
        ...

    # Signal handler: 
    def selection_changed(self, widget, data=None):
        (model, pathlist) = widget.get_selected_rows()
        for path in pathlist :
            tree_iter = model.get_iter(path)
            value = model.get_value(tree_iter,0)
            return value
```

As you see, selection_changed handler returns value. The question is how can I save that value after handler is called? I know that I can use a global variable or class attribute but it is not an option. I would like the code to look neat. i.e. like that:

```
tree_selection.connect("changed", value=self.selection_changed())
```

but of course it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't make sense for a signal handler to *return the value*, return it where?

The signal handler should be a method of a class where it makes sense to store the value as an attribute, ie:

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = None
        ...
        someTextView = build_textview("some text")
        ...
        tree_selection = someTreeView.get_child().get_selection()
        tree_selection.connect("changed", self.selection_changed)
        ...

    def selection_changed(self, widget, data=None):
        (model, pathlist) = widget.get_selected_rows()
        for path in pathlist :
            tree_iter = model.get_iter(path)
            value = model.get_value(tree_iter,0)
            this.value = value
            return
```

Notes:

- `__init__` method declares value attribute
- in connect method change `self.selection_changed()` for `self.selection_changed` so you pass the method itself and not the method's result.
- `selection_changed` method stores the value in the attribute and returns nothing.

Hope it helps.

**Update**

If you still feel your code will look nicer if it explicitly shows where it's storing the value, you could do something like this:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.value = None
    ...
    someTextView = build_textview("some text")
    ...
    def selection_changed_handler(widget, data):
        value = self.selection_changed(widget, data)

    tree_selection = someTreeView.get_child().get_selection()
    tree_selection.connect("changed", selection_changed_handler)
    ...
```

But I think the first one is the standard approach.

Comment: Well, in fact I know that it can be done like that but the question was if and how can you store the variable **returned** by signal hander? I will edit the question to avoid misunderstandings.

Comment: You can't store the return value. You are registering a function to be called by the TreeView object when selection changes, so your handler will return the value to a method in the TreeView object which doesn't care about the returned value.